# Different styles depending on button states? - Android

Tags: android, button

I have many custom buttons (ToggleButton) in my app and want to apply different styles for each button. I created a selector for all the buttons and I currently change only the drawable for the button, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient_selected" />

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient" />

</selector>
```

When I try to change the style the same way:

```
<item
   android:state_checked="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient_selected"
   style="@style/button_checked />
```

It does not work, I have tried to change the drawable in the style instead (and just stated the style in the selector), I've also tried to create a separate selector but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to do this.